# Фоновый режим работы приложения android

Tags: android, sip, java

У меня написан SIP-клиент, который совершает и принимает вызовы. Однако, при сворачивании приложения оно может выгрузиться из памяти и принимать вызовы соответственно не будет. Как реализовать приложение аналогично скайпу (до недавнего времени), когда по запуску он появляется в строке состояния и работает до тех пор, пока не нажата кнопка выхода? Наверняка существует статья на эту тему, но мои поиски не увенчались успехом.

Comment: ну есть класс Service, который может работать в режиме запрщающем выгрузку его из памяти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по вашим путаным показаниям речь идет о 3-х разных компонентах приложения:

1. [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) - компонента отвечающая *за появление значка в строке состояния*
2. [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) - некая долгоживущая компонента, в принципе можно сделать ее и невыгружаемой.
3. [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) - компонента отвечающая за перехват входящих звонков. Чтобы сделать ее "невыгружаемой", ее надо декларировать в манифесте с флагом `exported=true`

Композиционно делаем так:

1. Выставляем нотификацию, так чтобы при клике на нее стартовалась `Activity` вашего приложения
2. Вешаем `BroadcastReceiver` настроенный на фильтрацию входящих/исходящих SIP звонков. При перехвате звонка - `BroadcastReceiver` поднимет нужную `Activity`
3. Бизнес-логику приложения, которая должна быть всегда под рукой размещаем в `Service`, так чтобы из `Activity` можно было обратиться к `Service`.

P.S. ИМХО можно обойтись и без `Service` - но на вкус и цвет...